# DD4T and Keyword Metadata

Tags: tridion

Is keyword metadata currently exposed in the model DD4T creates?

I can see a Keyword type can be retrieved via the TaxonomyFactory/TaxonomyProvider - but this only exposes basic properties of the keyword itself, Id, Title, ParentKeywords etc.

Do we have roll our own mechanism at the moment - extend the DD4T Keyword in ContentModel.cs and use our own provider perhaps?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyword metadata is currently not exposed through DD4T. To be honest, it is not even very useful to do so. The essence of DD4T is to deserialize components and pages into a more useful object model than the one offered by the Tridion content broker. In the case of keywords, everything you would want to know about them is already in the broker database as metadata!

Besides, since keywords have no 'output', there is nothing to deserialize.

Code example (using the Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies namespace):

```
TaxonomyFactory tf = new TaxonomyFactory();
Keyword keyword = tf.GetTaxonomyKeyword("tcm:5-112233-1024");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
  "found keyword with name {0}, key {1}, description {2} and custom metadata {3}", 
  keyword.KeywordName, 
  keyword.KeywordKey, 
  keyword.KeywordDescription, 
  keyword.KeywordMeta));
```

Comment: I see your point, but the IKeyword interface doesn't even expose Description or Key fields - so whilst we could use the TaxonomyFactory to get a Keyword back, it doesn't contain all the fields we need.

Comment: I don't know about IKeyword, but Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies.Keyword gives access to the metadata, as well as description and key. I put a code example in my answer!

Comment: I guess we were looking for away for more richer keyword data to be part of the Model thats passed to our view. Firstly we want the description fields of the keyword as this is important for our localisation strategy and if we can add metadata then we won't need to make a extra call to the broker. Right now, we're looking at extending the ContentModel and Builder classes to. Cheers